# Image taking Double the space in imageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview

i have put an image in Imageview, but it is taking double the space. There is large gap between the image and textview beneath it. how can i set the image to use the height as per image?

My layout is as follows:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:gravity="center" android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/babyfa"

        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:text="@string/whatis"
    />
```

I have attached the imge, the red line represents the extra space the imageview is taking. kindly advise.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDOB3.jpg)

Comment: This has to be to do with the `scaleType` attribute. What is the original size of the image (in pixels)?

Comment: Its dimension is 640 X 426 pixels. Another question is Do i need to make different versions of it for different resolutions? i have made different version of icons(png) etc. or will android scale it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely being caused by `android:scaletype="fitStart"`. Try removing this from your XML. See [this helpful guide](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/) for the effects of different `scaletype` properties (`fitStart` is at the bottom).

Edit: Try also setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`. This will hopefully force the ImageView to preserve the image's aspect ratio.

Comment: Well removing scaletype didn't help. The image has now aligned itself to the center of imageview and imageview's height is the same.

Comment: <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/babyfa"


            />

Comment: I solved it by uing above code. Your link helped thanks.

Comment: No problem! Still, it's unfortunate that you had to resort to hard-coding in the height value. I'm sure there is a property that will remove the extra height without requiring you to hard-code anything. Android layouts can be tricky sometimes, but there's almost always a way. But if you're happy with your solution, no worries.

Comment: Well i did as u said and voila its working now without hardcoding any dimension. Thanks. Here is the code  <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/babyfa"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

            />

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help.